# Trimming frames from SWF Movieclip

Tags: flash

Is there a library or cli program which is capable of dropping/extracting frames from a SWF movie? Let's say I have a SWF movieclip with 451 frames, of which I will like to make a new movie clip out of with only the first 450 frames. No wrappers or containers though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. [swftools](http://www.swftools.org) can do it. After build the source just use swfextract.

```
swfextract -f 1-450 source.swf
```

Comment: thanks, but i've already tried that previously and it fails to keep the original SWF movie's frames intact. inspecting it with a decompiler, it seems as though whatever was on the scene is missing and only the assets relating to frames 1-450 are in the library.